# How to get faster for uv mapping to unwrap to match identical?

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

Does anybody know the answer? Can anyone help me out with this? I'm getting frustrated. Whenever I unwrap it, the result is random and doesn't match the identical body of the UV mapping I'm tired of doing this. I have all ways to put it to match the identical body of UV mapping. Why don't let Blender do it?

After unwrapping, it is random
[image]

It should auto-match correctly like this.
[image]

Comment: Hello, it's not clear what you mean, what should match what exactly?

Comment: I imagine he has two same meshes but the UV doesn't unwrap deterministically - probably the UV actually does unwrap deterministically, but is unstable and so some small change in the mesh makes a big change in uv unwrap.